# Alter SQL column based on comparison of number of elements

Tags: sql, group-by, conditional-statements, flags

I have a table with columns (Id, Prod, Id) and I must create a (Flag) like this:

```
Id Prod Id2 Flag
1  A    11  0
2  A    11  1
3  A    11  1
4  B    12  0
5  B    12  1
6  A    13  0
7  B    14  0
8  D    15  0
```

This (Flag) is created by grouping by (Id2) and assigning 0 for the lowest (Id) and 1 otherwise.

I tried using group by to no avail. How can I do that?

Comment: Please tag your database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression with a windowed function:

```
select tbl.*
    , case
        when row_number() over (partition by Id2 order by Id) = 1 then 0
        else 1
      end Flag
from tbl
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=76306027d0afd8e4f794c0fb701601ca)

You didn't tag a DBMS, so I've gone with SQL Server, but this should work for most.

Comment: If you want to write really portable SQL, ANSI SQL compliant, you have to do `tbl.*`. (ANSI SQL doesn't allow a single `*` to be combined with anything at all.) And some dbms product do it this _correct_ way.